# Unable mount at RdOnly

Tags: ubuntu, mount, wubi

This /etc/fstab use to work:

> UUID=some# /media/win7 ntfs  ro,auto,noexec,nosuid 0 0
>   media/win7/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/ubuntu ext4 loop,ro,noexec 0
>   0

To set the label on the ubuntu vol, I had to change the RdOnly flag to RdWr.

```
e2label /media/win7/ubuntu/disks/root.disk oldUbuntu
```

The ubuntu disk would mount ONLY if I kept the RdWr flag.  I'm not sure why.  I need to mount the vol as RdOnly.  I del the label `e2label /media/win7/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ""`.  I still can't mount the ubuntu vol as RdOnly.  Both the win7 & ubuntu vol's must be RdWr to get the ubuntu vol to mount.
`dmesg | tail` says:
EXT4-fs (loop0): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (loop0): write access unavailable, cannot proceed

What have I done wrong?  How can I fix it?

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gedit /etc/fstab`  Comment out the ubuntu vol.  Set my label again: `e2label /media/win7/ubuntu/disks/root.disk oldUbuntu`  Reboot the machine.  Mount the ubuntu vol as RW: `mount -t ext4 -o loop /media/win7/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/ubuntu`  ReEdit fstab, reinstate ubuntu vol as RdOnly.  Reboot.
Manually mounting the vol as RW, fixed the issue.